# Docker is not loading Node image from cache

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm using docker-compose in my local environment for development. I have 4 docker containers, 3 of them based on [docker-node](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/).

When I run `docker-compose up --build`, I see most of the building steps are loaded from cache, so they usually run really fast. But since a couple of days ago, I noticed they began to take a very long time to build (around 10 minutes in total), even if nothing had changed.

I also noticed that all the building steps seem to be loaded from cache, except for the first one: `FROM node:8`. And indeed, it always takes the longest to print the first step. Here's the complete output:

```
Building mongo-seed
Step 1/10 : FROM node:8
 ---> d575940ea42b
Step 2/10 : ENV NODE_ENV=development
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 64584d7c28d1
Step 3/10 : WORKDIR /seeder
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2481554b20cc
Step 4/10 : COPY ./server/app/models ./app/models
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ad6c76419ffd
Step 5/10 : COPY ./server/config ./config
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 379dd9e19e67
Step 6/10 : COPY ./server/util ./util
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1e6db5498a1a
Step 7/10 : COPY ./server/seed ./seed
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 659f531ef78d
Step 8/10 : COPY ./server/package.json ./package.json
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4eb54f2548b9
Step 9/10 : RUN npm i mongoose
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c34967921c69
Step 10/10 : CMD npm run seed
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0274c6635c1d
Successfully built 0274c6635c1d
Successfully tagged javorosas_mongo-seed:latest
Building server
^[Step 1/17 : FROM node:8
 ---> d575940ea42b
Step 2/17 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4cb3797b4737
Step 3/17 : RUN apt-get install -y graphicsmagick
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a33dcf53e585
Step 4/17 : RUN npm i -g webpack node-gyp nodemon
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c961ca565c54
Step 5/17 : ENV NODE_ENV=development
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c63d1a245873
Step 6/17 : WORKDIR /server
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7ac6181902ca
Step 7/17 : COPY ./server/package.json .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ebba732f0210
Step 8/17 : COPY ./common ../common
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 47a9e631cc57
Step 9/17 : RUN npm install --quiet && npm cache clean -f
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8d57a963d1ac
Step 10/17 : COPY ./server/constants ./constants
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a6a8884a1343
Step 11/17 : COPY ./server/util ./util
 ---> Using cache
 ---> dfd9de1db59e
Step 12/17 : COPY ./server/webpack.ssr.js .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 547282293bc6
Step 13/17 : COPY ./server/src ./src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e7821c59d012
Step 14/17 : RUN npm run build
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 184527650563
Step 15/17 : COPY . .
 ---> 8be425af57c7
Step 16/17 : EXPOSE 2018
 ---> Running in c662570856a5
Removing intermediate container c662570856a5
 ---> 1eb434d7e0ea
Step 17/17 : CMD npm run start:dev
 ---> Running in 613c7064436e
Removing intermediate container 613c7064436e
 ---> f37d511ffc78
Successfully built f37d511ffc78
Successfully tagged javorosas_server:latest
Building client
Step 1/10 : FROM node:8
 ---> d575940ea42b
Step 2/10 : RUN npm i -g webpack
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b8428ab7c232
Step 3/10 : ENV NODE_ENV=development
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bbfbbb480a46
Step 4/10 : WORKDIR /client
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2203bdaa2cea
Step 5/10 : COPY ./client/package.json .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fe5ead356992
Step 6/10 : COPY ./common ../common
 ---> Using cache
 ---> db9c274937cc
Step 7/10 : RUN npm install --quiet && npm cache clean -f
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 16be06b426b3
Step 8/10 : COPY . .
 ---> c96343b67244
Step 9/10 : EXPOSE 2017
 ---> Running in 7460e5f1d0c6
Removing intermediate container 7460e5f1d0c6
 ---> 8436f916f585
Step 10/10 : CMD npm run start
 ---> Running in fbcf8af08cbf
Removing intermediate container fbcf8af08cbf
 ---> 47958626245f
Successfully built 47958626245f
Successfully tagged javorosas_client:latest
javorosas_mongo_1 is up-to-date
Starting javorosas_mongo-seed_1 ... done
Recreating javorosas_server_1   ... done
Recreating javorosas_client_1   ... done
Attaching to javorosas_mongo_1, javorosas_mongo-seed_1, 
javorosas_server_1, javorosas_client_1
```

Any ideas on why it could have started to slow down?

Comment: Could you provide more informationn with regards to your environment? I assume you are on macos and use docker for mac. Something like: Version 18.03.1-ce-mac65 (24312)? If so: Have you already tried to reset 'docker for mac'? Hit the docker symbol in the menubar > Preferences > Reset. Before you do so make sure that all files you need to have persistent and not ephemeral are stored in folders you share with your docker images.

Comment: Are you using a Dockerfile?  If so, could you add it?

Comment: Hi. Yes, I use docker for mac and yes, I tried restarting the daemon, as well as rebooting my machine

Comment: @zero298 Yes, I am. I didn't see the need to do so because basically what the output shows is each line of my `Dockerfile`s. They look exactly the same.